# Show Ip address in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to show the customer ip in the sales order grid in admin section.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id',array('remote_ip') );
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

But its returns:-

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.*, `sales_flat_order`.`remote_ip` FROM
>   `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`  INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order`
>   ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id = main_table.entity_id',array('remote_ip') );

Comment: It's not worked for me.

Comment: It solved the error what you mentioned. So are you still getting error or not showing ip in grid?

Comment: Have you checked? It works?